# Rspec guidance on repetitive expect

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec-rails

I have a test case like this.

```
subject(:report) { @report.data }
it { expect(report[0][:id]).to eq(@c1.id) }
it { expect(report[1][:id]).to eq(@c2.id) }
it { expect(report[2][:id]).to eq(@c3.id) }
it { expect(report[0][:title]).to eq("Announcement3") }
it { expect(report[1][:title]).to eq("Announcement2") }
it { expect(report[2][:title]).to eq("Announcement1") }
```

I feel this is not really an efficient way.

Is there any other way to make it efficient ? So that it looks like one line condition.

Comment: Is `@report.data` an Array of Hashes?

Comment: Array of hashes it seems!

Comment: @fivedigit Yes. It is array of hashes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Test Behavior, Not Composition

Always test *behavior*, not composition. What you ought to be testing here is the *behavior* that given some set of fixed inputs, a report will generate the same fixed output every single time. You aren't doing that; you're introspecting individual report elements, which is about *composition*.

Instead, consider using fixtures or FactoryGirl (or even just a setup block) to define fixed inputs, and then check that:

```
it 'creates valid report data' do
  expect(@report.data).to eq @sample.data
end
```

### More on Behavior

If each element of your report is coming from a different method, you ought to be testing the behavior of each of those methods separately, rather than decomposing the final report. That is another way to make your test clearer and more meaningful, and addresses the "unit" in unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather write something like this:

```
it { expect(report[0]).to include(id: @c1.id, title: "Announcement3") }
it { expect(report[1]).to include(id: @c2.id, title: "Announcement2") }
it { expect(report[2]).to include(id: @c3.id, title: "Announcement1") }
```

It does not get that deep into report structure and for me looks more readable.

Comment: Replace `eq` with `include` and I'm with you. That way, if there are other pieces of information that might be included, but we don't care about for this test, they can still be included without breaking it.

Comment: Totally agree, however if you want a strict test, stick to eq

Comment: Agreed, but the test above is strictly testing specific keys, not the full structure of each report hash. `include` covers that better than `eq` in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You could map reports to the keys you care about and make expectations on that:

`expect(report.map { |h| h[:title] }).to eq [array, of, values]`

You could use `include` to check each report member's keys:

`expect(report[0]).to include id: @c1.id, title: "Announcement3"`

You could build an "expected" object and test equality:

```
expected = [{ id: @c1.id, title: "Announcement3" }, ...]
expect(report).to eq expected
```